# Differential Equations Uniquenes Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem states:
"In Exercises $1$-$4$ we refer to a function $f$, but we do not provide it's formula. However, we do assume that $f$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Uniqueness Theorem in the entire $xy$ plane, and we do provide various solutions to the given differential equation. Finally we specify the initial condition. Using the Uniqueness theorem, what can you conclude about the solution to the equation with the given initial condition?"

$$ dy/dt = f(y)$$
$$ y_1(t) = 4\ for\ all\ t\ is\ a\ solution,$$
$$ y_2(t) = 2\ for\ all\ t\ is\ a\ solution,$$
$$ y_3(t) = 0\ for\ all\ t\ is\ a\ solution,$$
$$ initial\ condition\ y(0)\ =1 $$

I'm incredibly confused by this, and have absolutely no idea where to even begin.

Answer (score 0):

$y_1(t)=4$ is a solution, This means that
$$
y_1'(t)=f(y_1(t))\quad\forall t,
$$
that is $0=f(4)$. You can reach similar results about the value of $f$ at $y=2$ and $y=0$.

Next, $0<1<2$. By uniqueness, two different solutions cannot cross (the graphs of the solutions do not cross.) What does this tell you about the unique solution $y$ with $y(0)=1$?